# Typecast each object in an array on a single line of code, using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Say I've got an array of `User`:

```
class User : IUserDowngraded
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
}
```

... with downgraded functionality done by casting the objects to a specific interface:

```
interface IUserDowngraded
{
    Int32 Id { get; } // removes set functionality from property
}
```

... how would I cast those downgraded objects (`IUserDowngraded`) to `User` objects in a single line of code, using LINQ?

What I'm trying to avoid is this:

```
// pseudo-code alert:
IUserDowngraded[] downgradedUsers { IUserDowngraded, IUserDowngraded, ... };

var upgradedUsers = new User[downgradedUsers.Count()];

Int32 i = 0;

foreach (IUserDowngraded du in downgradedUsers)
{
    upgradedUsers[i] = (User)user;

    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var upgradedUsers = downgradedUsers.Cast<User>();
```

Append a call to `ToArray()` if you want `upgradedUsers` as an array, of course.

Comment: Guess I kind'a missed that method. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, LINQ has lots of goodies that are easy to miss... This is a particularly useful one. :)

Answer (score 0):

[use the cast method....](http://www.linqexchange.com/post/2008/05/How-to-Convert-a-Collection-From-One-Type-to-Another-Type-Using-LINQ-Cast.aspx)

```
SampleIntList = SampleStringList.Cast<int>().Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Also any of [Implicit operators, Linq and Lambda expressions can make code less readable. But what is more readable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809533/implicit-operators-linq-and-lambda-expressions-can-make-code-less-readable-but) methods should work.