# Why does this cast-operation fail

Tags: c#, linq, casting, struct

i've got this struct

```
[Serializable]
public struct Foo : IConvertible, IXmlSerializable, IComparable, IComparable<Foo>
{
    private readonly int _value;

    private Foo(int id)
    {
        this._value = id;
    }

    private IConvertible ConvertibleValue
    {
        get
        {
            return this._value;
        }
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Foo)
        {
            var foo = (Foo) obj;
            return this.CompareTo(foo);
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int CompareTo(Foo other)
    {
        return this._value.CompareTo(other._value);
    }

    public TypeCode GetTypeCode()
    {
        return this._value.GetTypeCode();
    }

    bool IConvertible.ToBoolean(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return this.ConvertibleValue.ToBoolean(provider);
    }

    char IConvertible.ToChar(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return this.ConvertibleValue.ToChar(provider);
    }

    sbyte IConvertible.ToSByte(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return this.ConvertibleValue.ToSByte(provider);
    }

    byte IConvertible.ToByte(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return this.ConvertibleValue.ToByte(provider);
    }

    short IConvertible.ToInt16(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return this.ConvertibleValue.ToInt16(provider);
    }

    ushort IConvertible.ToUInt16(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return this.ConvertibleValue.ToUInt16(provider);
    }

    int IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return this.ConvertibleValue.ToInt32(provider);
    }

    uint IConvertible.ToUInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return this.ConvertibleValue.ToUInt32(provider);
    }

    long IConvertible.ToInt64(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return this.ConvertibleValue.ToInt64(provider);
    }

    ulong IConvertible.ToUInt64(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return this.ConvertibleValue.ToUInt64(provider);
    }

    float IConvertible.ToSingle(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return this.ConvertibleValue.ToSingle(provider);
    }

    double IConvertible.ToDouble(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return this.ConvertibleValue.ToDouble(provider);
    }

    decimal IConvertible.ToDecimal(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return this.ConvertibleValue.ToDecimal(provider);
    }

    DateTime IConvertible.ToDateTime(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return this.ConvertibleValue.ToDateTime(provider);
    }

    string IConvertible.ToString(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return this.ConvertibleValue.ToString(provider);
    }

    object IConvertible.ToType(Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return this.ConvertibleValue.ToType(conversionType, provider);
    }

    XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        var stringId = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringId))
        {
            return;
        }

        this = int.Parse(stringId);
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(this);
    }

    public static implicit operator int(Foo value)
    {
        return value._value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Foo(int value)
    {
        Foo foo;
        if (value > 0)
        {
            foo = new Foo(value);
        }
        else
        {
            foo = new Foo();
        }
        return foo;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this._value.ToString();
    }
}
```

now i'm failing this:

```
var intList = new List<int>
{
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
};
var fooList = intList.Cast<Foo>().ToList();
```

with

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
>    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__aa`1.MoveNext()
>    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>    ...

Comment: See [Why does a Linq Cast<T> operation fail when I have an implicit cast defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808725/why-does-a-linq-castt-operation-fail-when-i-have-an-implicit-cast-defined) and its linked threads.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason why is that the `Cast` function is written against generic types (i.e. not concrete types).  It looks a bit like the following

```
public IEnumeralbe<T> Cast<T>(this IEnumerable source) { 
  foreach (object cur in source) {
    yield return (T)cur;
  }
}
```

The cast operation inside of `Cast` can only be done on this generic information which does not include the specialzed cast operator on `Foo`.  Hence this code does not consider the implicit conversion here and instead *essentially* relies on CLR conversions only.

In order to get this working you need the cast to be done against the `Foo` type directly.  The best way to do this is with a select

```
var fooList = intList.Select(x => (Foo)x).ToList();
```

Comment: :)) the ctor with int-param is private ... sorry mate ... no chance with that ... is there any other solution instead of the `.Select()`?

Comment: @Andreas, missed the private ctor.  Select is your best bet here.  It's really suited for this purpose as it represents a projection which is what needs to happen here