# Casting List<x> to List<y>

Tags: c#, list, casting

The following code works:

```
List<JsonStock> stock = new List<JsonStock>();

foreach(tblStock item in repository.Single(id).tblStocks)                
    stock.Add((JsonStock) item);
```

So naturally you'd think that this code would work too:

```
List<JsonStock> stock = repository.Single(id).tblStocks.Cast<JsonStock>().ToList()
```

But I get the error `Invalid cast operation` - does anybody know why that might happen?

**UPDATE**

*tblStocks* is a list of LINQ to SQL object, tblStock.
*JsonStock* is a simplified version of the tblStock class and gets returned to a webpage as a JSON object.

The following operator was built to do the casting:

```
public partial class tblStock{
    public static explicit operator JsonStock(tblStock stock){
        JsonStock item = new JsonStock
        {
            boxes = stock.boxes,
            boxtype = stock.tblBoxType.name,
            boxtype_id = stock.boxtype_id,
            grade = stock.grade,
            packrate = stock.packrate,
            weight = stock.weight
        };

        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: how is the type of `tblStocks` defined?

Comment: Just an idea, not sure of this: `repository.Single(id).tblStocks` returns an array or list of `JsonStock`, so when you try to cast as `JsonStock` it complains...

Comment: @Marco - no it shouldn't complain.

Comment: Try `foreach(tblStock item in repository.Single(id).tblStocks.Cast(JsonStock))` with the debugger, and look at which it crashes (by counting how many it inserted in the `List<> stock`)

Comment: What version of C# are you using? In C# 4 covariance/contravariance should be supported.

Comment: @Daniel: thanks, so I'm waiting to know which is `tblStocks` type...

Comment: What is the relation between tblStock and JsonStock?

Comment: Assuming tblStocks is an IEnumerable of JsonStock, your code should work. So what "is in tblStocks"? I assume there are also objects of inherited "JsonStock" classes in there, cause that would cause the cast exception.

Comment: @UrbanEsc - the cast to a base class from a sub class should work.

Comment: Yes, you are of course right. It would help to get to know the definition of tblStocks and tblStock

Comment: Take a look at List.ConvertAll

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Cast` is used to change a non-generic collection into a generic one, i.e. it performs an unboxing operation. It can't be used the way you want.
When you have a look at the implementation of `Cast` and the `CastIterator` it uses, you see, that it takes an object and casts it to the specified type:

```
foreach (object current in source)
{
    yield return (TResult)current;
}
```

This only works if `current` really is a `TResult`. No custom conversions are applied in this case.
This is the default behavior, you can test it yourself:

```
double d = 0.0;
object tmp = d;
int i = (int)tmp; // throws the same exception you are getting
```

What you want is best achieved with a simple `Select` if `tblStocks` is a generic enumerable:

```
List<JsonStock> stock = repository.Single(id).tblStocks
                                  .Select(x => (JsonStock)x).ToList();
```

Or, if `tblStocks` is a non-generic enumerable, you need to combine `Cast` and `Select`:

```
List<JsonStock> stock = repository.Single(id).tblStocks.Cast<tblStock>()
                                  .Select(x => (JsonStock)x).ToList();
```

This will first unbox the objects in `tblStocks` to their real type (`tblStock`) and then cast it to the type you want (`JsonStocks`).

Answer (score 2):

implicit and explicit conversion operators are [ignored by Cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808725/why-does-a-linq-castt-operation-fail-when-i-have-an-implicit-cast-defined). In your case that means that

```
 public static explicit operator JsonStock(tblStock stock)
```

is ignored by Cast they are however not ignored in the foreach case

Comment: Says who? If that would be true `Enumerable.Cast<T>()` would make no sense at all. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx contains no information to support your claim.

Comment: @VVS: You don't understand the purpose of `Enumerable.Cast<T>()`. The input is a non-generic enumerable. The result is a generic enumerable. The whole purpose of this extension method is to create a strong typed enumerable from a non-generic enumerable you know the type of the objects from. See my answer for more details.

Comment: @VVS If read carefully that link does indeed contain information to support my claim as does the link in my answer.
The link you've supplied talks about _cast_ operators the above is a _conversion_ operator. The syntaxt for using both is the same (SomeType) but that does not make them the same. So I really don't get your downvote

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Cast, consider using OfType. In Cast, if the item you are processing isn't the destired type, you will get the InvalidCastException. With OfType, it will trap for invalid cast and only return items that actually are the type that you are looking for.

```
List<JsonStock> stock = repository.Single(id).tblStocks.OfType<JsonStock>().ToList()
```

If you return empty lists however, I would suspect that your tblStocks actually is not returning JsonStocks and you are trying to project some other type (tblStock?) into a DTO (JsonStock). If the later is the case, you need to use Select to project into the new type from the underlying type.

```
List<JsonStock> stock = repository.Single(id).tblStocks
                        .Select(stock => new JsonStock 
                             { 
                               Id = stock.Id,
                               Val1 = stock.Val1,
                               Val2 = stock.Val2,
                               ...
                             }
                         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

- `tblStocks.Cast<JsonStock>()` performs a cast.
- `(JsonStock) item` performs a cast **or applies a custom-defined conversion**.

Since tblStock is a LINQ to SQL class and JsonStock is a custom class created by you, none is a subtype of the other. Thus, you cannot cast between the two.

To fix this, you can use the `Select` clause of LINQ and manually convert the elements:

```
 List<JsonStock> stock = repository.Single(id).tblStocks
     .Select(item => (JsonStock) item).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh, the wonders of explicit operator overloads.

So to fix your problem you might want to call a Select beforehand.

```
List<JsonStock> stock = repository.Single(id).tblStocks.Select(x => (JsonStock)x).ToList()
```

However i'd say that this operator overload is something you should get rid of. Consider replacing it with a copy constructor like implementation

```
class JsonStock
{
     public JsonStock(tblStock other)
     {
          // copy values here
     }
}
```