# Why can you use LINQ to cast an enumerable using Select, but not Cast<>?

Tags: c#, linq, casting

I was trying to create an enumerable containing a series of doubles from 0 to X. My first attempt was:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Cast<double>();
```

But this gives the error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Double'.

If I can't cast int32 to double, then why does the following work?:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => (double) i);
```

Comment: Do these answer your question?  [Explicit/implicit cast operator fails when using LINQ's .Cast() operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13316718/3744182) and [Why does a Linq Cast<T> operation fail when I have an implicit cast defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/808725/3744182).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does a Linq Cast<T> operation fail when I have an implicit cast defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808725/why-does-a-linq-castt-operation-fail-when-i-have-an-implicit-cast-defined)

Comment: Thanks guys, didn't see those. They answer my question.